# Who is that girl who attacked Daenerys in the episode "Valar Dohaeris" (S03E01)?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Season 3 Episode 1 (Valar Dohaeris)* a young girl attempts to assassinate **Daenerys** with a scorpion-like creature and then disappears. 
Daenerys is saved by a cloaked Barristan Selmy.

Who is that girl, and why did she attack Daenerys?

Comment: I thought it was mentioned right in that scene that this girl was some kind of incarnation of the sorcerers that stole her dragons in *Qarth* at the end of season 2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a Clash of Kings,
As Daenerys visits the docks of Qarth in order to find passage, Ser Jorah alarms her that they are being followed by two men, a fat brown man (15 stone weight and covered in scars) and an older man with a Westerosi appearance (with a white beard and a staff). Ser Jorah and Daenerys notice the men using a large brass platter in a ship and attempt to escape them. Just then the brass merchant takes after them and pesters them to buy the platter which they do just to get rid of the man.

At that moment, the Qartheen thrusts a carved wooden case disguising it to be a gift to the Mother of Dragons which on opening seems to contain a valuable scarab. As she reaches for it, the scarab unfolds with a hiss. But before the manticore could sting her, whitebeard sends the box pummeling away with his staff and crushes the creature with the end of his staff. Danys' bloodriders attempt to confront the two men but she narrates the incident to them and by the time she sends out her bloodriders to nab the perpetrator, A Sorrowful Man, he has since long disappeared.

The two men turn out to be Strong Belwas and Whitebeard.

In A Clash of Kings, Daenerys turns to the Warlocks after she's refused aid by the Pureborn, the ruling elite of Qarth. Daenerys' dragons kill the Undying Ones to save their "mother" from the ancient warlocks. After Daenerys leaves the House of the Undying, many Qartheen factions, including the warlocks, call for Daenerys to be killed and one of them sends a Sorrowful Man to assassinate her. Pyat Pree also gathers the remaining warlocks to work ill on Dany.

The TV series changed the Sorrowful Man assassin hired by one of the Qartheen factions to a warlock who appeared as a young girl, though both attempted to kill her with a poisonous Manticore. Also, in the books the assassination attempt occurred as Daenerys was leaving the docks of Qarth, while the TV series slightly changed this by having it occur at Astapor's docks just as she arrived from Qarth.

Answer (score 4):

I believe she was an assassin, sent by the Warlocks to assassinate Dani.

Did I miss anything or is it as simple as this?

Comment: The book is slightly different, but from a TV continuity, you've nailed it.

Comment: Well we know she wasn't "just an assassin" because we see her jump into the water and teleport onto a nearby rooftop without making a splash. We also see her blue lips, a clear sign that she herself is a warlock.

Comment: And? She is, basically, a one shot character. Whether she is a warlock or not makes no real difference as she has never been involved before and never appears again.

Comment: Could the dive bomber let me know how the answer could be improved? Or is it a certain someone just trying to be spiteful? :-) (you know who you are!)